# Count degrees of freedom of a polynomial

Tags: matrix, performance-tuning, linear-algebra

I want to count the independent degrees of freedom of a polynomial in three variables $(z_0,z_1,z_2)$. Therefore I take the coefficients of $f$ and compute the rank Jacobian with respect to the coefficients.

```
MatrixRank[D[Union@Flatten@CoefficientList[f,{z0,z1,z2}], {coefficients}]]
```

with

```
f=(-((z0^3 "i"[1] + z0^2 z1 "i"[2] + z0 z1^2 "i"[3] + z1^3 "i"[4] + z0^2 z2 "i"[5] + z0 z1 z2 "i"[6] + z1^2 z2 "i"[7] +        z0 z2^2 "i"[8] + z1 z2^2 "i"[9] + z2^3 "i"[10])^2 +      4 z0 (z0^5 "j"[1] + z0^4 z1 "j"[2] + z0^3 z1^2 "j"[3] + z0^2 z1^3 "j"[4] + z0 z1^4 "j"[5] + z1^5 "j"[6] +         z0^4 z2 "j"[7] + z0^3 z1 z2 "j"[8] + z0^2 z1^2 z2 "j"[9] +         z0 z1^3 z2 "j"[10] + z1^4 z2 "j"[11] + z0^3 z2^2 "j"[12] +         z0^2 z1 z2^2 "j"[13] + z0 z1^2 z2^2 "j"[14] +         z1^3 z2^2 "j"[15] + z0^2 z2^3 "j"[16] + z0 z1 z2^3 "j"[17] +         z1^2 z2^3 "j"[18] + z0 z2^4 "j"[19] + z1 z2^4 "j"[20] +         z2^5 "j"[21]))^2 +   24 (z0 (z0^3 "i"[1] + z0^2 z1 "i"[2] + z0 z1^2 "i"[3] +         z1^3 "i"[4] + z0^2 z2 "i"[5] + z0 z1 z2 "i"[6] +         z1^2 z2 "i"[7] + z0 z2^2 "i"[8] + z1 z2^2 "i"[9] +         z2^3 "i"[10]) (z0^8 "k"[1] + z0^7 z1 "k"[2] +         z0^6 z1^2 "k"[3] + z0^5 z1^3 "k"[4] + z0^4 z1^4 "k"[5] +         z0^3 z1^5 "k"[6] + z0^2 z1^6 "k"[7] + z0 z1^7 "k"[8] +         z1^8 "k"[9] + z0^7 z2 "k"[10] + z0^6 z1 z2 "k"[11] +         z0^5 z1^2 z2 "k"[12] + z0^4 z1^3 z2 "k"[13] +         z0^3 z1^4 z2 "k"[14] + z0^2 z1^5 z2 "k"[15] +         z0 z1^6 z2 "k"[16] + z1^7 z2 "k"[17] + z0^6 z2^2 "k"[18] +         z0^5 z1 z2^2 "k"[19] + z0^4 z1^2 z2^2 "k"[20] +         z0^3 z1^3 z2^2 "k"[21] + z0^2 z1^4 z2^2 "k"[22] +         z0 z1^5 z2^2 "k"[23] + z1^6 z2^2 "k"[24] + z0^5 z2^3 "k"[25] +         z0^4 z1 z2^3 "k"[26] + z0^3 z1^2 z2^3 "k"[27] +         z0^2 z1^3 z2^3 "k"[28] + z0 z1^4 z2^3 "k"[29] +         z1^5 z2^3 "k"[30] + z0^4 z2^4 "k"[31] + z0^3 z1 z2^4 "k"[32] +         z0^2 z1^2 z2^4 "k"[33] + z0 z1^3 z2^4 "k"[34] +         z1^4 z2^4 "k"[35] + z0^3 z2^5 "k"[36] + z0^2 z1 z2^5 "k"[37] +         z0 z1^2 z2^5 "k"[38] + z1^3 z2^5 "k"[39] +         z0^2 z2^6 "k"[40] + z0 z1 z2^6 "k"[41] + z1^2 z2^6 "k"[42] +         z0 z2^7 "k"[43] + z1 z2^7 "k"[44] + z2^8 "k"[45]) +      2 z0 (z0^11 "l"[1] + z0^10 z1 "l"[2] + z0^9 z1^2 "l"[3] +         z0^8 z1^3 "l"[4] + z0^7 z1^4 "l"[5] + z0^6 z1^5 "l"[6] +         z0^5 z1^6 "l"[7] + z0^4 z1^7 "l"[8] + z0^3 z1^8 "l"[9] +         z0^2 z1^9 "l"[10] + z0 z1^10 "l"[11] + z1^11 "l"[12] +         z0^10 z2 "l"[13] + z0^9 z1 z2 "l"[14] + z0^8 z1^2 z2 "l"[15] +         z0^7 z1^3 z2 "l"[16] + z0^6 z1^4 z2 "l"[17] +         z0^5 z1^5 z2 "l"[18] + z0^4 z1^6 z2 "l"[19] +         z0^3 z1^7 z2 "l"[20] + z0^2 z1^8 z2 "l"[21] +         z0 z1^9 z2 "l"[22] + z1^10 z2 "l"[23] + z0^9 z2^2 "l"[24] +         z0^8 z1 z2^2 "l"[25] + z0^7 z1^2 z2^2 "l"[26] +         z0^6 z1^3 z2^2 "l"[27] + z0^5 z1^4 z2^2 "l"[28] +         z0^4 z1^5 z2^2 "l"[29] + z0^3 z1^6 z2^2 "l"[30] +         z0^2 z1^7 z2^2 "l"[31] + z0 z1^8 z2^2 "l"[32] +         z1^9 z2^2 "l"[33] + z0^8 z2^3 "l"[34] + z0^7 z1 z2^3 "l"[35] +         z0^6 z1^2 z2^3 "l"[36] + z0^5 z1^3 z2^3 "l"[37] +         z0^4 z1^4 z2^3 "l"[38] + z0^3 z1^5 z2^3 "l"[39] +         z0^2 z1^6 z2^3 "l"[40] + z0 z1^7 z2^3 "l"[41] +         z1^8 z2^3 "l"[42] + z0^7 z2^4 "l"[43] + z0^6 z1 z2^4 "l"[44] +         z0^5 z1^2 z2^4 "l"[45] + z0^4 z1^3 z2^4 "l"[46] + z0^3 z1^4 z2^4 "l"[47] + z0^2 z1^5 z2^4 "l"[48] +         z0 z1^6 z2^4 "l"[49] + z1^7 z2^4 "l"[50] + z0^6 z2^5 "l"[51] +         z0^5 z1 z2^5 "l"[52] + z0^4 z1^2 z2^5 "l"[53] +         z0^3 z1^3 z2^5 "l"[54] + z0^2 z1^4 z2^5 "l"[55] +         z0 z1^5 z2^5 "l"[56] + z1^6 z2^5 "l"[57] + z0^5 z2^6 "l"[58] +         z0^4 z1 z2^6 "l"[59] + z0^3 z1^2 z2^6 "l"[60] +         z0^2 z1^3 z2^6 "l"[61] + z0 z1^4 z2^6 "l"[62] +         z1^5 z2^6 "l"[63] + z0^4 z2^7 "l"[64] + z0^3 z1 z2^7 "l"[65] +         z0^2 z1^2 z2^7 "l"[66] + z0 z1^3 z2^7 "l"[67] +         z1^4 z2^7 "l"[68] + z0^3 z2^8 "l"[69] + z0^2 z1 z2^8 "l"[70] +         z0 z1^2 z2^8 "l"[71] + z1^3 z2^8 "l"[72] +         z0^2 z2^9 "l"[73] + z0 z1 z2^9 "l"[74] + z1^2 z2^9 "l"[75] +         z0 z2^10 "l"[76] + z1 z2^10 "l"[77] + z2^11 "l"[78])))
```

and

```
coefficients = {"i"[1], "i"[2], "i"[3], "i"[4], "i"[5], "i"[6], "i"[7], "i"[8],  "i"[9], "i"[10], "j"[1], "j"[2], "j"[3], "j"[4], "j"[5], "j"[6],  "j"[7], "j"[8], "j"[9], "j"[10], "j"[11], "j"[12], "j"[13], "j"[14],  "j"[15], "j"[16], "j"[17], "j"[18], "j"[19], "j"[20], "j"[21],  "k"[1], "k"[2], "k"[3], "k"[4], "k"[5], "k"[6], "k"[7], "k"[8], "k"[23], "k"[24], "k"[25], "k"[26], "k"[27], "k"[28], "k"[29],  "k"[30], "k"[31], "k"[32], "k"[33], "k"[34], "k"[35], "k"[36], "k"[37], "k"[38], "k"[39], "k"[40], "k"[41], "k"[42], "k"[43],  "k"[44], "k"[45], "l"[1], "l"[2], "l"[3], "l"[4], "l"[5], "l"[6],  "l"[7], "l"[8], "l"[9], "l"[10], "l"[11], "l"[12], "l"[13], "l"[14],  "l"[15], "l"[16], "l"[17], "l"[18], "l"[19], "l"[20], "l"[21],  "l"[22], "l"[23], "l"[24], "l"[25], "l"[26], "l"[27], "l"[28], "l"[29], "l"[30], "l"[31], "l"[32], "l"[33], "l"[34], "l"[35],  "l"[36], "l"[37], "l"[38], "l"[39], "l"[40], "l"[41], "l"[42],  "l"[43], "l"[44], "l"[45], "l"[46], "l"[47], "l"[48], "l"[49],  "l"[50], "l"[51], "l"[52], "l"[53], "l"[54], "l"[55], "l"[56],  "l"[57], "l"[58], "l"[59], "l"[60], "l"[61], "l"[62], "l"[63],  "l"[64], "l"[65], "l"[66], "l"[67], "l"[68], "l"[69], "l"[70],  "l"[71], "l"[72], "l"[73], "l"[74], "l"[75], "l"[76], "l"[77],  "l"[78]}
```

Sadly, the computation of the matrix rank does not terminate after 24 hours. I do not understand why it take so long to compute the rank of a $92\times 154$ matrix.

What is the reason for that? And is there any way to speed up the calculation?

Comment: I would say you should never use MatrixRank on a symbolic matrix, because `MatrixRank[{{a, b}, {c, d}}]` yields `2` which may be wrong.

Comment: In my case the coefficients are themselves generic functions. Therefore `MatrixRank[{{a, b}, {c, d}}] = 2` would be the correct answer for me.

Comment: `MatrixRank` does not do any column reordering (possibly it should). An observation is that your matrix has some complicated elements, mostly in the first or at least earlier positions in their rows. Reversing all rows will not alter the rank (in effect we are just reordering columns from last to first). With the resulting matrix the row reduction is effective. `In[416]:= rmat = Map[Reverse, mat];
Timing[rank = MatrixRank[rmat]]

Out[417]= {0.046800, 82}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Before using `MatrixRank` remove columns/rows consisting of zeros only. Also, when a row/column contains precisely 1 non-zero element, delete the corresponding column/row that contains the non-zero element and count one rank.

```
mat = D[Union@Flatten@CoefficientList[f,{z0,z1,z2}], {coefficients}]

rank[m_] := Module[{rank = 0, mat = m, c1, c2},
               With[{rows = Map[Length[DeleteCases[#, 0]] &, mat]},
                 mat = Delete[Transpose[Delete[mat, Position[rows, 0]]],
                   Map[Position[#, n_ /; n =!= 0, {1}, 1, Heads -> False][[1, {1}]] &,
                     Extract[mat, c1 = Position[rows, 1]]]]];
               With[{cols = Map[Length[DeleteCases[#, 0]] &, mat]},
                 mat = Delete[Transpose[Delete[mat, Position[cols, 0]]],
                   Map[Position[#, n_ /; n =!= 0, {1}, 1, Heads -> False][[1, {1}]] &,
                     Extract[mat, c2 = Position[cols, 1]]]]];
               MatrixRank[mat] + Length[c1] + Length[c2]]

rank[mat]
(*82*)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I think you have to change the first line to `mat = D[Union@Flatten@CoefficientList[f,{z0,z1,z2}], {coefficients}]`.